# eZ publish link tables

Tags: symfony, ezpublish

I need to combine two classes, Job and User.

When the User is on a Job item he can press on an "apply" button and is then assigned to a Job. When the HR clicks on the Job, all the users that are inside that Job should be visible.

So I need a table "job_user".
How can I do this in the most effective way? With Doctrine?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

I would use a relation attribute on User to link that object to a Job. This way you leverage existing features in eZ and don't have to worry about creating and maintaining your own schema.

https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/The+Relation+FieldType